# Is it possible to replace loops with numpy BUT for functions not included in that module

Tags: python, numpy

This question is for python purposes. For example if I have an array which's elements are strings. Can I print out the length of every element with the len() function?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(["qwerty", "uiop", "as"])
# and here is the actual example
arr.len()
```

That last row doesn't work as you can guess, but I'll be really thankful if there is something like this and I manage to find it <3

My goal is to find something better than for loops.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's a poor example since there is `numpy.char.str_len` "in that module" ;-)

Comment: `np.char` applies a number of the string methods to elements of string dtype array.  However since it is calling python methods, it isn't particularly fast - not like the compiled numeric methods.  Operating on an object dtype array might actually be faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) method, and apply it on the built-in `len` function:

```
vect_len = np.vectorize(len)

>>> vect_len(arr)
array([6, 4, 2])
```

Note that this gets rid of your explicit loop, but the implementation is still a loop under the hood. As stated in the docs:

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

You can also use [`np.frompyfunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc) to the get the same, and might see a little better performance on large arrays (but it's less readable):

```
vect_len2 = np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)

>>> vect_len2(arr)
array([6, 4, 2], dtype=object)
```

Testing performance on large dataframes:

```
import timeit

arr = np.random.choice(arr,1000000)

vect_len = np.vectorize(len)
vect_len2 = np.frompyfunc(len, 1, 1)

def using_vectorize(arr=arr):
    return vect_len(arr)

def using_frompyfunc(arr=arr):
    return vect_len2(arr)


>>> timeit.timeit(using_vectorize,number=10)/10
0.17760197920142673
>>> timeit.timeit(using_frompyfunc,number=10)/10
0.11580852449988015
```

`frompyfunc` tends to do a little bit better, but you'll only see a noticeable difference on huge arrays

Honestly, a good old list-comprehension would do as an alternative for small arrays (although you said you didn't want loops):

```
>>> [len(i) for i in arr]
[6, 4, 2]
```